input type number se pone a cero hasta que guardo
Tengo este formulario:


<form method="post" action="edit_sale_detail.php?id=<?php echo (int)$sale_detail['id']; ?>" autocomplete="off">
  <td class="text-center" style="width:115px;" id="s_code">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="code" placeholder="Código" value="<?php echo ' VE '.str_pad($sale_detail['sale_id'],4,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).'/24 '; ?>" readonly minlength="6" maxlength="6">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="product_id" placeholder="Producto" value="<?php echo remove_junk($sale_detail['product_id']); ?>">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="qty" placeholder="Cantidad" value="<?php echo remove_junk($sale_detail['qty']); ?>">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="price" placeholder="Precio" value="<?php echo remove_junk($sale_detail['price']); ?>" step="0.01">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="total" placeholder="Total" value="<?php echo remove_junk($sale_detail['total']); ?>" step="0.01" readonly autocomplete="off">
  </td>
  <td>
    <button type="submit" name="update_sale_detail" class="btn btn-danger">Actualizar producto de venta</button>
  </td>
</form>



El ultimo input type number muestra el producto de otros dos input anteriores, uno de ellos también lleva el step y funciona bien, pero este, una vez hago el producto, si no le doy al botón de guardar y presiono en otro sitio, se pone a 0.
Al presionar el botón guardar, en la bbdd se guarda bien, pero sino, muestra 0,00.
Aqui recojo los valores y actualizo:
$sd_pid=$db->escape($_POST['product_id']);
$sd_qty=$db->escape($_POST['qty']);
$sd_price=$db->escape($_POST['price']);
$sd_total=$sd_qty*$sd_price;
$sql="UPDATE sale_details SET";
$sql.=" product_id='{$sd_pid}',qty='{$sd_qty}',price='{$sd_price}',total='{$sd_total}'";
$sql.=" WHERE id='{$sale_detail['id']}'";


Hola Charly, ¿podrías agregar el código que implementaste para calcular el producto?

'$sd_total=$sd_qty*$sd_price;'

Charly, presiona [edit] y agrega el código en tu pregunta. De todas formas, si no entendí mal, deberías tener un código en Javascript, no? Tenes 2 <input> donde ingresas datos y en el 3ro imprimís el resultado de multiplicar los valores ingresados, correcto?

lo hago con php, ya esta editada la pregunta

¿Vos queres esperar a guardar los datos para ver el total actualizado? PD: No tiene mucho sentido guardar datos "calculados" en la DB, es información redundante y/o se presta a error.

en realidad, si se guarda bien en la bbdd y cuando se carga la pagina se ve bien, me da igual. Yo pensaba que al cambiar un input, si esta relacionado con otro se actualizaba, o por lo menos, no macaba 0.

Continuemos el debate en el chat.
